# Less brightness after plugging once my macbook pro to a thunderbolt display

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, color, thunderbolt-display, display

I own a Macbook pro (15'4) with Yosemite.

I used to use it without an external display. 
The brightness was very powerful :)

I've just plugged a thunderbolt display (Mac 27''), and then removed it. 
I even restarted my MacBook pro right after.

Now, I found that the brightness is not as powerful as before, even on MAX :(

My color profile is the one by default (LCD color).

Is there an explanation? 
Have someone ever experienced this?

Comment: You could try to fix this with a PRAM reset on startup (hold cmd+alt+p+r) until your mac restarts. (https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761)

Comment: !! It works... Is it a REAL bug with apple 27 display ?

Comment: Not that i know of, give me a few minutes to explain in an answer ;)

Comment: Also, have a look here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a NVRAM reset by starting your mac and holding the following keys:

`CMD + ALT + R + P.`

[(More info)](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18761)

When your Mac restarts, you could release the keys.

> Some say that you have to do this 3 times for the best result, but I can't explain why

More information about a PRAM/NVRAM reset can be found on the [Apple Support Website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

When you use your Mac and connect it to displays or change the screen's brightness, it could be that your settings become a bit corrupted. You could erase those settings by preforming a PRAM reset as explained above.

I can't find any known bugs on the Apple Diagnostics website, you could report it by sending a mail to feedback@apple.com

Comment: Very useful, I think I will write to feedback@apple.com as suggested. Thanks !